# Is there such a word as "Gestern-heute" and if yes what does it mean?

Tags: translation, german-to-english

The news had something that happened on this date a few years ago(9-11) and it had in the title "Gestern-heute" if I remember correctly. What does it mean?

EDIT

To make the question clearer I am not looking for the meaning of "gestern" or "heute", but if putting them together has a meaning. I don't remember the sentence but it was talking about the 9-11 events in 2001.

Comment: It would tremendously help us to understand and explain  *"gestern - heute"* if you could find a more elaborate quote of the line/context you read it.

Comment: @Grantwalzer I know what each word means by itself, I am just not sure if putting them together means anything

Comment: Ah! Well, if you would have included this information in your question, it would probably have an answer by now :)

Comment: @Takkat i updated question

Comment: There is "gestern Morgen" (Yesterday morning) which may be confusing to some because Morgen can mean both morning and tomorrow.

Comment: Ein ähnliches Konstrukt, "Heute morgen", hat eine besondere Bedeutung, jedoch nur, weil "morgen" doppeldeutig ist. Ansonsten kann ein Sendungstitel eine Verkürzung sein und "Die Welt gestern u. heute im Vergleich" bedeuten, oder etwas derartiges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably not supposed to be one word, because

> gesternheute

seems contradictory (an antinomy), except maybe in the sense of "either yesterday and/or today" ([and then](https://www.google.at/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=gesternheute&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=IFQRVNXDPKuG8Qflt4Ag#channel=fs&q=gestern-heute) it would be my first encounter with it). Meaning: As things are standing it doesn't have some acknowledged meaning. You can still interpret meaning into it, like you can into *Eckenschirm*.

Otherwise it's a comparison or timespan between yesterday and today.

Comment: Even in German you can't combine all types of words. If there were such a term, it would probably be written in two words like other daytimes, for example "morgen Abend" or "heute Morgen". It's most certainly a comparison or timespan.

Answer (score 26):

I guess the “-” in “gestern-heute” is not meant as a hyphen, but rather as a dash. So it should be written “gestern – heute”. Both words are used here in a figurative sense, representing past and present. So I would expect the article to contrast past and present aspects of the 9/11 attack.

A word *gestern-heute* or *gesternheute* doesn’t exist, as Grantwalzer already confirmed.

Comment: That’d also be my guess. If the newspaper would place value on typography, it probably should have been: »Gestern – heute« ([Halbgeviertstrich](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halbgeviertstrich) with spaces instead of [Viertelgeviertstrich](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viertelgeviertstrich) without spaces).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. (Not sure how common it is on German.SE, but a comment like this is incredibly helpful on programming SEs.)

Answer (score 4):

It might have been a "bis-Strich" (I don't know the English term for that). In that case it was probably typeset not as a hyphen (-) but as an en-dash (–).

If that is the case, "gestern–heute" would mean "gestern bis heute", "from yesterday to today".

Generally, the "bis-Strich" is used to denote ranges, like "von 3–5 Uhr" (from 3 to 5 o'clock), or "Seite 36–42" (pages 36 to 42).

Answer (score 0):

from yesterday to today (timespan); maybe what has changed, how was it back then, and how is it now (the situation)

Comment: This answer is difficult to understand, if at all. Please you use complete sentences and be a more verbose.